# Encrypting a "stream" with AES

Tags: c++, encryption

I continuously produce a string that I need to write to a local file (encrypted).

As I'm already having an AES library in my application, I would prefer to use AES - if possible.

Approach 1: AES has a block size of 16 bytes, so I need to buffer 16 bytes of data in memory that I might lose if the computer crashes.

Approach 2: Writing all the data to the file first and periodically encrypt the whole file with AES-CBC. This way, the user could access the unencrypted file for a short period of time.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Are you expecting a computer crash?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The computers running the application are often not shut down properly but instead are just powered-off

Comment: AES can be used as a stream cipher. A starting point: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65085/using-aes-as-a-stream-cipher

Comment: "The user could access the unencrypted file". Well, of course. Encryption protects against man-in-the-middle attacks. That's not a property for a short period of time, that's fundamental.

Comment: Use [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7), most implementations support it and it all happens in the functions, that is padding is automatically added on encryption and removed on decryption.

Answer (score -1):

Since you probably can't write 15 bytes to disk anyway, pad out your data to a multiple of 4KB (minus whatever header you need) and encrypt the padded data.

Comment: Why pad to 4KB? AES is generally padded with [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Comment: @zaph: Because that's what your typical filesystem uses (if not a multiple). Don't focus on just the crypto part, the question here is about persistence in the presence of power outages.

Comment: Do you pad you text files, binary files, etc or do you let the system, you know, the OS, do that for you. And it isn't just getting it on disk, the directory entry needs to be made and the allocation routines must run, the caches flushed.